# simple way to detect connection timeout for dataservice

Tags: apache-flex, busyindicator, dataservice

I'm developing a mobile project which gets some simple data trough a dataservice. When the application is getting the data i've got a busyindicator spinning, but i don't want it spinning forever (because of a bad connection or no connection at all). Is there a way to set a limit, say 30 seconds, and then display a SkinnablePopUpContainer?
Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which connection type you use there are probably events you can trap for 'lost connection', 'inbound data', etc. You can also start a timer before you open the connection and check if you've received anything when it goes off.

Comment: The connectiontype is http service. I'm quite new at flex, so any example code would be great. I just can't find any good examples of how to handle this anywhere. The idea of starting a timer seems to be the most logical, since I've already have a resulthandler and a faulthandler running (for the busyindicator). Again; some samplecode would realy push me in the right direction, or maybe some documentation.

Comment: Doesn't look like HTTPService has any better events. Try the Timer. http://blog.flexexamples.com/category/timer/

Comment: Thanks for the response ethrbunny, but arn't those timers from the blog MX components? I can't seem to find a Spark alternative.

Comment: Isn't spark just a view framework? Surely the actionscript hasn't changed.. much?